# Why doesn't the background colour of my Storyboard in Xcode change? It's always the same grey color?

Tags: ios, background, storyboard

So i've changed the background property of my default view in my storyboard file to as many as the colours in the rainbow. The colour shows up along with my buttons nicely in Xcode, but when I actually RUN the app, the background is always the same, ugly, default grey colour that you start with a new Xcode project ("Hello World!").

I've searched up for the answer all over Google and to no avail. Am I doing something wrong or is it just a glitch? It might be also important to mention than i'm using Spritekit, and that this "view" is the only view in my Storyboard file, the default one. Should I change self.view to skView? Would that work?

Oh and also, when I manually try to change the background colour under viewDidLoad in my .m class by doing:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor backgroundColor];
```

the background STILL doesn't change and is always the same default colour. Please help me... i'm desperate right now... there's no answers anywhere to be found. Thanks.

Comment: Which view? What is your view hierarchy?

Comment: It's hard to tell the problem with the information provided, It is highly probable that you are changing the colour later in code, check the lifecycle methods of the view or put some code so that we can find the problem

Comment: By "Hello World!", do you mean *Single View Application"? What does your Storyboard look like?

Comment: I'd love to provide you with some more code examples but unfortunately the only code I have that refers to my background is the one above. Most of my problem is something to do with the storyboard. :/ I'll try posting some screenshots however.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect My only view hierarchy is the one default view that the storyboard file comes with :/

Answer (score 3):

All Storyboard, all graphical answer:

[image: Storyboard]

Explanation: You should modify the *Main.storyboard*, select the *View Controller*, change `View` in the *Attribute Inspector*, and apply a new **Background** color.

With exactly **0 lines** of code, you should get this result:

[image]

Download project [here](http://swiftarchitect.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/S0-35049609.zip).

Comment: Thanks Swift, I appreciate the answer. However, when I do the same thing my output is pure grey and it makes me feel frustrated beyond belief because others can get this simple concept and I can't. I also tried it on default code and it didn't work for me. I'm using SpriteKit by the way, if that helps in any way or effects the circumstances. Also i'm not using Swift, i'm using Objective-C... really wish i'd pick the other way around but it's too late now.

Comment: Not related to the language (swift or Obj-c) since there is no line of code involved

Comment: Added a project for you to inspect at http://swiftarchitect.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/S0-35049609.zip

Comment: You're right, I just tried it out for myself and the background colour changes when it's supposed to with a one-view app in both obj-C and Swift. However, I chose to use Xcode's game development kit, which has GameScene, maybe that is the cause of all my and life's problems? The background seems to be transparent when you try to change it using Game kit.

Comment: Update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just try checking that you don't have a line saying 'self.view.backgroundColor = ...' inside of your .m file. i.e. somewhere in 'loadView:', 'viewDidLoad:' or 'viewWillAppear:'

(I first thought that you have linked to some different viewController inside of your storyboard, but if you have all your buttons displaying correctly, then this assumption is wrong)

If you just want a quick fix of the problem, then simply add a line in your .m file saying `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];`

Comment: but why do this programmatically? It is a storyboard question.

Comment: if you read it carefully, it says "If you just want a quick fix of the problem..."

Comment: \-: I generally seek 0 lines of code solutions, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Doesn't work, like I said, even manually changing the background colour of my view under viewDidLoad does nothing

Answer (score 0):

The `UIView`.[`backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622591-backgroundcolor) property is inherited by `SKView`, but is visible only if the SpriteKit view isn't rendering any SpriteKit scene.

Of course, in practice a SpriteKit view just about always has an `SKScene` assigned to it. When the view is rendering a scene, it paints itself with the [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1520278-backgroundcolor) of whatever scene it's assigned to render.

(This means that if you [present](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview/1519705-presentscene) a different scene, the background will change. It also means that if your scene's [`scaleMode`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519562-scalemode) and size are such that the scene doesn't fill the entire view, the view's [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622591-backgroundcolor) will be visible in areas not covered by the scene.)

---

You can set an `SKScene`'s background color in code using its [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1520278-backgroundcolor) property. If you create your scene graphically in an `.sks` file, you can set it in the inspector pane in Xcode:

[image: scene editor inspector with color control]

**IMPORTANT:** This is the *SpriteKit Scene inspector*, seen when you  edit a `.sks` file in Xcode -- ***not*** the view / view controller inspector that you see when editing a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem as me! That you see the ugly gray background right after the SplashScreen, I have found a solution! Just after creating the skView, create an empty scene with a white background and present it directly!

```
let backgroundColoredScene = SKScene()    
backgroundColoredScene.backgroundColor = SKColor.white()    
skView.presentScene(backgroundColoredScene)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to change the background color at main.storyboard as above, then restart Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same exact problem. After finding no help whatsoever online and exhausting myself trying different things; I decided to simply add a view to the storyboard and make it the background. This way you can change the background color and/or image and it will show up. It should be entirely constrained to the superview. I used the following constraints:

[image: constraints]

If you need to add other things to the storyboard (which it wouldn't really make any sense if you didn't) every other object should be contained in this view (it basically replaces the superview). This works well for me and I hope it can help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the SKView. A workaround I use is to change the SKView on the storyboard to a UIView. Then transition to an ViewControler with an SKView when you want to run your spritekit game.
[Here's where you can change the view type on the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k02IB.png)