# Unable to change background of new view when using spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, storyboard

I am using SpriteKit to make a game. However I have 2 viewcontrollers, MenuViewController and the GameViewController. The background of MenuViewController is not changing color and is stuck on the default grey. Whenever I try to change the color using the attributes inspector nothing happens. I don't have any code in the MenuViewController to change the background and when I do add the code it is still the default grey color.

I have looked everywhere on google and have found nothing about this problem. Any ideas would be helpful.

This is similar to this one that never got answered:

[Why doesn't the background colour of my Storyboard in Xcode change? It's always the same grey color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049609/why-doesnt-the-background-colour-of-my-storyboard-in-xcode-change-its-always/35050106#35050106)

edit - Here are some screenshots to better explain:
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OpgK.png)
[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6MWc.png)
I forgot to mention this originally, but the MenuViewController uses a storyboard and is a UIView.

Comment: Answered the duplicate question.

Comment: @rickster My question is different. Also you didn't really answer the question considering in both question it mentions how we tried changing the background in the attribute inspector and nothing happened.

Comment: Read more closely and be careful which file's inspector you're using. If you change the background color in the storyboard, you're setting the view background color, which gets obscured by the SpriteKit scene's background color. If you edit the .sks file instead of the storyboard, you can use *its* inspector to change the SpriteKit scene's background.

Comment: It's not visible from your screenshot whether MenuViewController also has a SpriteKit view (though clearly you're not drawing its UI with SpriteKit). Check the class in the class inspector.

Comment: @rickster Exactly. The view doesn't have a scene linked to it. Is a scene needed for all views in a spritekit app? The GameView which does load a scene does not have background problems.

Comment: You probably have an SKView that's presenting an empty SKScene on your menu screen. If you aren't actually trying to do anything with SpriteKit there, just use a basic UIView instead of SKView — then the storyboard inspector will do what you want, and the view won't be needlessly spinning the CPU at run time.

Comment: @rickster I looked in the attribute inspector and found that the view was somehow a SkView even though it said otherwise in the class. Thank you for the help :)